# Vector of differences of Brownian motion integrals is multivariate normal

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Given a 2-dimensional Wiener process $(W_{1},W_{2})$ with correlation $\rho$.

Let \begin{equation*} X(t):= F(t) + \int_{0}^{t} f(s) dW_{1}(s) + \int_{0}^{t} g(s) dW_{2}(s)\end{equation*}
for some nice enough deterministic functions $F$, $f$ and $g$.
Let now $0<t_{1}<t_{2}<\ldots < t_{n+1}$ and $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n+1 \}$. We define $X_{i}:=X(t_{i})$ and
\begin{equation*} Y_{k}:= (X_{k}-X_{i})_{i\neq k}=(X_{k}-X_{1},\ldots,\widehat{X_{k}-X_{k}},\ldots,X_{k}-X_{n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.  \end{equation*}
I know would like to understand the following claim:

$Y_{k}$ has a multivariate normal distribution.

Any help or references would be appreciated very much.

As a follow-up:

I figured that the definition of 2-dimensional Wiener process $(W_{1},W_{2})$ with correlation $\rho$ is not quite clear to me.
I assume that $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ being one-dimensional Wiener processes and $corr(W_{1}(t),W_{2}(t))=\rho$ is not enough, isn't it!?

I would assume that we have to assume that $(W_{1}(t),W_{2}(t))$ has a two-dimensional normal distribution with mean 0.

Generally, is there a standard definition for a n-dimensional Wiener process with correlation? If so, I would be happy to get some references.

Else, my guess would be that a n-dimensional stochastic process $W=(W_{1},\ldots,W_{n})$ is a n-dimensional process with:

1. $W(0)=0$ a.s.
2. $W_{t}$ a.s.-continuous
3. increments are independent
4. $W_{t}-W_{s}\sim N(0,\Sigma)$, for $t>s$

where

$\Sigma$ is a positive-definite and symmetric matrix with diagonal elements equal to $t-s$

Comment: $(\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n)$ is multi-normal iff any combinations $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \xi_i$ is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, the random vector $Y_k$ is multi-normal if for any combinations 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i\ne k} a_i (X_k-X_i) \tag{1}
\end{align*}
is normal. WLOG, we assume that $1<k<n+1$. Note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i\ne k} a_i (X_k-X_i) &=-\sum_{i\ne k}a_i X_i +X_k \sum_{i\ne k} a_i\\
&=-a_{n+1}(X_{n+1}-X_n)\\
&\quad -(a_{n+1}+a_n)(X_n-X_{n-1})\\
&\quad - \cdots \\
&\quad -\sum_{i=k+1}^{n+1} a_i(X_{k+1}-X_k)\\
&\quad +\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i(K_k-X_{k-1})\\
&\quad +\cdots\\
&\quad +a_1(X_2-X_1).
\end{align*}
Since $(W_1, W_2)$ is a 2-dimensional Brownian motion, by Cholesky decomposition,
\begin{align*}
W_1(t) &= B_1(t),\\
W_2(t) &= \rho B_1(t) + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}B_2(t),
\end{align*}
where $B_1$ and $B_2$ are two independent Brownian motions. Then,
for $i=2,\ldots, n+1$, 
\begin{align*}
X_i-X_{i-1} &= F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1}) + \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}f(s)dW_1(s) + \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}g(s)dW_2(s)\\
&= F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1}) + \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}(f(s)+\rho g(s))dB_1(s) + \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}g(s)dB_2(s)
\end{align*}
is normal. Moreover, since
\begin{align*}
(X_2-X_1),\, \ldots, \, (X_{n+1}-X_n)
\end{align*}
are independent, their combinations 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i\ne k} a_i (X_k-X_i)
\end{align*}
is also normal. That is, $Y_k$ is multi-normal.

Comment: In fact, I was considering the case where $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ are not necessarily indenpendent, but have correlation $\rho$. Can one then adapt your argument?

Comment: In that case you can use that $W_2(t) \sim \rho W_1(t) + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2} W_3(t)$ where $W_3$ is another independent Brownian motion and where $\sim$ denotes equality in distribution.

Comment: I actually have a follow-up question: see above

Comment: See Appendix A of the book [Stochastic Differential Equations](https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Differential-Equations-Introduction-Applications/dp/3540047581/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1505492439&sr=8-1&keywords=oksendal) by Oksendal.

Comment: The reference just seems to treat multidim. normally distributed random variables and not really what I was looking for (see above)

Comment: Can you please ask another instead?

Comment: ask as another question